# iOS In App Purchase returning zero product in archived build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am using Swift 5, and created IAP product with Auto-Renewal subscription.
I am able to get product if in debug mode and **`Debug executable`** is checked.
[Project Scheme image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYAZI.png)
but if I uncheck the Debug Executable then its returning zero products.
Even if I archive build and upload to TestFlight , its not returning product.

I am using below method to get product:

```
    // MARK: - SKProductsRequestDelegate
extension IAPManager: SKProductsRequestDelegate {
    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("Loaded list of products...")
        let products = response.products
        guard !products.isEmpty else {
            print("Product list is empty...!")
            print("Did you configure the project and set up the IAP?")
            productsRequestCompletionHandler?(false, nil)
            return
        }
        productsRequestCompletionHandler?(true, products)
        clearRequestAndHandler()
        for p in products {
            print("Found product: \(p.productIdentifier) \(p.localizedTitle) \(p.price.floatValue)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution to this problem?